# Searching thru NSArray to post to Tableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an NSArray loaded with objects (see below).   I need to load these into a tableview based on which indexpath.row is clicked from another tableview.

If a user selects indexpath.row = 0, then the second tableview is reloaded with ORDER_CODE's which contain only GROUP = 0.
If the user selects indexpath.row = 1, then the second tableview is reloaded with ORDER_CODE's which contain only GROUP = 1.

Anyone have any advice/coding on how I can search thru the array and display the relevant data into the second tableview?

```
array=(
        {
        GROUP = 0;
        "ORDER_CODE" = 410;
        "PROD_DESCR" = "cement";
        id = 0;
    },
        {
        GROUP = 0;
        "ORDER_CODE" = 411;
        "PROD_DESCR" = "concrete";
        id = 1;
    },
        {
        GROUP = 1;
        "ORDER_CODE" = 405;
        "PROD_DESCR" = "asphalt";
        id = 2;
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code to filter the results (on clicking a particular tablerow) from the given array

```
NSArray *array; //your data array

//create a search predicate to filter the array
NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary * evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    BOOL isValidGroup = [evaluatedObject[@"GROUP"] integerValue] == indexPath.row;
    return isValidGroup;
}];

NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate]; //this is the filtered array you can use for the displaying in the table
```